# How do I get my split token out of my results?

Tags: ruby, string, split

Using Ruby 2.4.  I want to split my string on breaking or non-breaking spaces, however, the below expressions

```
str = "aa 11:22 bb 33.44:55 cc dd 123"
#=> "aa 11:22 bb 33.44:55 cc dd 123"
str.split(/(\t|[[:space:]])+/)
#=> ["aa", " ", "11:22", " ", "bb", " ", "33.44:55", " ", "cc", " ", "dd", " ", "123"]
```

include spaces in the results.  How do I do the split such that the spaces aren't included in the results?

Comment: `str.scan(/\S+/)` works for your example.

Comment: Why use `\t` and `[:space:]` if the latter matches the former? Just use `str.split(/[[:space:]]+/)`

Comment: Hey Wiktor, If the string is " aaa", then using your expression results in ["", "aaa"] .  Notice the empty element at teh beginning -- I'd like to avoid taht.

Comment: Then use `s.scan(/[^[:space:]]+/)`, or if you would use split, use `s.strip.split(/[[:space:]]+/)` (or `lstrip`, depends on what you need to get in the end). I think you need to show more example strings with expected behavior in your question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, suppose `str = "\u00A0cat"#=> " cat"` (`\u0001t` being a non-breaking space). Then `str.strip #=> " cat"`, so 
`str.strip.split(/[[:space:]]+/) #=> ["", "cat"]`.

Comment: Then [`s.sub(/\A[[:space:]]+/, '').split(/[[:space:]]+/)`](http://ideone.com/btSWja).

Comment: See [`str.gsub(/\A[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+\z/, '').split(/[[:space:]]+/)`](http://ideone.com/NCKWuB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `" "`'s in your array because `(\t|[[:space:]])` is a capture group. Use a non-capture group:

```
str.split(/(?:\t|[[:space:]])+/)
  #=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
```

See [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split).

You can do the following if you want to split on breaking or non-breaking spaces and do not want a string of the same at either the beginning or end of the resulting array.

```
str = " \u00A0aa\t11:22\u00A0bb 33.44:55 cc dd 123  "

str.gsub(/\A[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+\z/,'').split(/[[:space:]]+/)
  #=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
```

Comment: Hi Cary, If str = " \u00A0aa\t11:22\u00A0bb    33.44:55 cc dd 123  ", and then apply what you have, the result is ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "", "", "", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"] (notice all teh blank elements).  any way to eliminate those?

Comment: @Dave, I am unable to reproduce your result. I see that I somewhere lost the `+` after the second `[[:space:]]` (put it back in), but that did not account for the result you report. Please recheck.

Answer (score 2):

```
str.split(/[[:space:]]/)
#=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
```

For your test data just `split` would work:

```
str.split
#=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
```

Few more options using using different input string:

```
str = "aa\t11:22\tbb 33.44:55 cc dd 123"
str.split(/\t|[[:space:]]/)
#=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
str.split(/\s+/) # one more way
#=> ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"]
```

Comment: Thanks.  But if the string is "aa\t11:22\tbb  33.44:55 cc dd 123" (note multiple spaces between words), the result using your split is ["aa", "11:22", "bb", "", "33.44:55", "cc", "dd", "123"] .  Note the empty element in there.

Comment: @Ilya I think spaces *is* the problem and OP wants the opposite: `How do I do the split such that the spaces aren't included in the results?`

Comment: BTW, `split(/\s+/)` will produce the same output.

Comment: @Ilya yea, there are definitely more than one way to do that. Please, feel free to edit my answer with this one :)

Comment: I don't think there's ever a need for "edit" in an answer. My advice is that you act as though you're writing a book. If you think your answer (a section of the book) can be improved, just rewrite it. If you want readers to know you've done an edit you can inform them in a comment, as you've done here. Readers can always look at the edit history if they want to see what you had before.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see what you mean here. This makes sense.